# Nested Regexmatch Not Working on Range of Zeros and Ones

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have a sum filter formula and have nested a REGEXMATCH function within it as a condition to filter the range to be summed.

The full formula looks like:

```
=sum(filter(data,
region1=$AF$4,
industry=$A11,
quarter=AG$9,
REGEXMATCH(consent,"1")))
```

The range "consent" is just 0 or 1 for each value in the range.

When I run this function 0 is returned whereas I expect about 1,000.

The [documentation for REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en) says

> "This function only works with text (not numbers) as input and returns
>   text as output. If a number is desired as the output, try using the
>   VALUE function in conjunction with this function. If numbers are used
>   as input, convert them to text using the TEXT function."

I'm not sure what to do with that. I tried the following:

```
REGEXMATCH(consent,1) // no luck
REGEXMATCH(TEXT(consent),"1") // no luck
REGEXMATCH(TEXT(consent),TEXT(1)) // no luck
```

But, if I do this:

```
REGEXMATCH(consent,".*") // does work for all data in consent
```

How can I tell GSheets to REGEXMATCH on the range consent where it equals 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the documentation is a bit misleading, because while you can convert to text using the `TEXT` function (which [requires a second argument that prescribes the format of the output](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en), which is why your attempt was not working), it is probably not the easiest way to do it. Probably better would be `TO_TEXT`, or simply appending `&""`:

`REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(consent),"1")`
`REGEXMATCH(consent&"","1")`

That being said, is there a reason you can't just use `consent=1` (in which case, you could just use `consent` by itself as an argument in `FILTER`)?

Comment: Thank you very much, my formula is working now and I can go home for the day!
I could not use consent=1 because the worksheet is interactive for the client and given the range of options available tot he user, regex seemed way to go (Sometimes they will select where all values (1|0) others just 1).